# Spring boot and h2. Can't change db name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

I have such configuration file:

```
spring.datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;MODE=MySQL

server:
  port: 9001
```

my main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringJmsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringJmsApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Resource
    DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        log.info("Creating tables" + jdbcTemplate.toString());
        log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + dataSource.getConnection().getCatalog()+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE xxx(" +
                "id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255))");
}
}
```

In my console http://localhost:9001/console/ I enter into my db with url parameter jdbc:h2:mem:mydb and can't find my table, but with parameter jdbc:h2:mem:testdb I see my xxx table. How to fix this issue?

```
dataSource.getConnection().getCatalog()
```

Always returns "TESTDB"

Comment: Maybe helps: http://h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases

Comment: @tt why do you care, it is an in-memory database anyways. Probably, you have a valid usecase, which I am curious to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` dependency in your `build.gradle` file.

Replace:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE
```

with:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
```

It's probably `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` handles this properties processing.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-core', version: '5.7.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-broker', version: '5.15.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.activemq.junit', name: 'activemq-junit', version: '5.15.0'
    
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')  
}

Comment: @ttt, you must be missing something? There is no h2 dependency here

Comment: sorry, it's another project

Comment: compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.196'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-core', version: '3.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '1.5.7.RELEASE'

Comment: @ttt, see my updated question. Also, edit you question and add `build.gradle` file, so that others could find it

Comment: @ttt, let me know if it helps or not

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your applicaton.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```